# Sidekiq Delayed Mailer not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, sidekiq, delayed-execution

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to use Sidekiq/Redis to send emails in the background.  I should note the following:

1. I am using `devise-async` and it works with no issues
2. My `ActionMailer` settings are good
   If I change my mailer calls to `UserMailer.contact_email(name).deliver!` The email sends just fine.  What is not working is `UserMailer.delay.contact_email(name)`
3. I can see the jobs going through in my logs, and you'd even go so far as to assume the mails were making it through. It was only when I sent to myself that I noticed it wasn't working:
   `Apr 08 18:36:58 app01-production sidekiq:  2013-04-09T00:36:58Z 31155 TID-1jdwoq Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass JID-6143790ebbf6e8bbc4a7bb85 INFO: done: 4.923 sec`

It is obviously calling the DelayedClass extension on the mail object, but no-go.  Given that `devise-async` works, I'm wondering if I am using the wrong syntax or something?`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit into a similar issue too. I made a tiny change in the way the delayed extension calls #deliver.

Try this out: `gem 'sidekiq', :git => "git@bitbucket.org:benjamintanweihao/sidekiq.git"`.

If this works out for you, then it might due to `msg.from` not being set.

The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb?#L23).

Comment: Hi Benjamin - thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately I'm going off the grid on vacation for a month so won't be able to try until then. Appreciate it though. I'll accept as it seems reasonable :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually i have same problem when use rails 4 version. The solution above not working for me, i have check @benjamin repo and can't found it . So, i have try sidekiq mailer gem https://github.com/andersondias/sidekiq_mailer and get it work well!